# Change value of a single attribute for multiple UID's at once in LDAP

Tags: ldap, forgerock, apache-directory

I have a list of uid's of several users present in LDAP and I need to replace the value of one attribute for all those uid's to a new value. Is there a way to accomplish this via Apache Directory Studio at once without editing each entry manually. I am very new to this and this is not my area of expertise. Also, I am aware of only Apache Directory Studio to play around with LDAP values. If someone can provide their inputs with the same, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

In Apache Directory Studio, you can right-click a connection and select "Import" then "LDIF Import". The file would look something like this

```
dn: cn=user1FQDN,ou=OrgUnit,o=MyOrg
changetype: modify
replace: TheAttribute
TheAttribute: NewValue
-

dn: cn=user2FQDN,ou=OrgUnit,o=MyOrg
changetype: modify
replace: TheAttribute
TheAttribute: NewValue
-

dn: cn=user3FQDN,ou=OrgUnit,o=MyOrg
changetype: modify
replace: TheAttribute
TheAttribute: NewValue
-
```

When I'm trying to set the same value on a lot of accounts, I'll put together a quick script to grab the list of user DNs and write the rest of the LDIF content.

Where the "dn" value is each user's fully qualified DN, TheAttribute is the name of the attribute you want to update, and NewValue is the value you want to write into TheAttribute.

Use care when using LDIF to import changes -- you can pull in a lot of changes quite quickly, but you can also screw up a lot of accounts quite quickly. You need to understand the difference between "changetype: modify" which updates an *attribute* (the update could be to remove the attribute, but the changetype is still modify) and "changetype: delete" which deletes the *object*. You'll also want to understand how modify/delete operations. Using "changetype: modify" with just "delete: TheAttribute" would delete *everything* in the attribute:

```
dn: cn=user1FQDN,ou=OrgUnit,o=MyOrg
changetype: modify
delete: TheAttribute
-
```

If you want to delete a single value of a multi-value attribute, you need to use:

```
dn: cn=user1FQDN,ou=OrgUnit,o=MyOrg
changetype: modify
delete: TheAttribute
TheAttribute: ValueToDelete
-
```

To specify *which* TheAttribute you want to delete.